# In Sqlalchemy, what's different in defining table using Base and Table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I know i can define a table using Table:

```
user = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key = True),
)
```

and using Base:

```
Base = declarative_base()    
class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'user'
        user_id= Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
```

but what's the different???

Comment: In first example you're defining only a table, in second both a table and a class mapping to this table. This is a _declarative_ mapping style, which is more concise than _classical_ mapping, where you must define tables and mappings separately. I recommend to read SQLAlchemy docs, at least both ORM and Core tutorials to get a better grasp of SA basics.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas I'd add that as an answer if you add some links because it *answers* the question and there is not much more to say. The declarative style is just a combination of `Table` and `Mapper` to make it easier for the user (and cleaner to read). Everything else should be read from the docs anyway.

Comment: [Types of Mappings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_styles.html) just for everyone else who comes across this

Answer (score 20):

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', Unicode(64))
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
metadata = MetaData()

user = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', Unicode(64)),
)

class User(object):
    pass

mapper(User, user)  # this will modify the User class!
```