# Select from table defined by SQLAlchemy declarative_base

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am working on FastAPI tutorial and I am trying to create tables using SQLAlchemy+Alembic+[databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/).
In my `main.py` I have:

```
from typing import List

import databases
import sqlalchemy
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Table

DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test.db"

database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

notes = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "note",
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column("id", sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("text", sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("completed", sqlalchemy.Boolean),
)

class Note2(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: str
    completed: bool

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await database.connect()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await database.disconnect()

@app.get("/notes/", response_model=List[Note2])
async def read_notes():
    query = notes.select()
    return await database.fetch_all(query)
```

And this works - I can `GET` **/notes/** endpoint. But it looks newbie to create a datatabase table in the same module with endpoints, so I decided to make `models.py` file and create a normal model there, like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = "note"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = sa.Column(sa.String)
    completed = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)
```

And here comes a problem - when I change the endpoint like this:

```
from app_second.models import Note

@app.get("/notes/", response_model=List[Note2])
async def read_notes():
    query = Note().select()
    return await database.fetch_all(query)
```

I recieve an error:

> AttributeError: 'Note' object has no attribute 'select'

As it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33166392/8495108) - `declarative_base()` is just a syntactic shugar for `Table` + `mapper`. But what is the right way to select/filter/update tables declared that way?

Comment: `Note` is an ORM model, so you would have to do `session.query(Note).filter(...)`.  `note` is a `Table`, and can be accessed as `Note.__table__`

Comment: @snakecharmerb yep, I think it should work with normal SQLALchemy flow, but I am trying to use `databases` to make code async - and it does not use `session` (at least in tutorials it is made like I have).

Comment: @snakecharmerb but looks like `Note.__table__.select()` works also. :) But is that the best way to do that? Usually, it does not look a good way to use dunder methods/attributes in the python code.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) seems to cover using declarative style models with FastApi

Comment: @snakecharmerb but as I see - endpoints there are synchronous, without `async def ...` For me that part of tutorial looks like just as an explanation of synchronous database connection...

Comment: Hmmm you're right, my bad.  Looks like declarative is not supported by design - https://github.com/encode/databases/issues/76 (although see also https://github.com/encode/databases/issues/105)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **table** property to access the table methods and then use database.fetch_all() or similar. E.g:

```py
from sqlalchemy import select
    
...
skip = 0
limit = 100

query = (
    Note.__table__.select()
    .offset(skip)
    .limit(limit)
)
return await database.fetch_all(query)
```